# How to change this format?

Tags: javascript, excel

Here i want to get the Data from Excel File by using upload file control.My Snippet is

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fup1');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('txt1');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            txt1.innerText = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);

    });
}
```

when i run this code i get the data in below format

PK!q9+p��[Content_Types].xml ��(�̔MN�0��H�!�%n��j�?K��ؓƪc[���g��
P�T��DQ4���f��|[�d��9g#���Ni�����Cz���*a�����|v~6}�y���-欌��p���J`�

how can i resolve this please help me

Comment: @RobH:please give me example..i dont know how to do it...please

Comment: Excel uses a very specialized format to store the data. You won't be able to read data from Excel file without a library which can decode this data. I don't think there exist any such library in JavaScript. You can take a look at Java library - Apache Poi

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh this actually exists: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to understand what you are doing. You are taking a exel file( which is not in a txt format) converting it into fileStream( buffer of bytes) finally you are converting it into txt file( which was a exel file). So what do you expect the result.

Now try Solving this problem using two popular JavaScript libraries:

1. [xls](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls)

2. [xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

Which allow you to parse in pure JavaScript.

For Documentation of these two libraries you can refer to following link.

[Documentation](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)